# Detecting if a "space" has been typed in a UITextField, and moving to a next UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm new to Swift and I'm implementing a small form into a solution. I have three UITextFields and I want to make it so that if I type in a word and then type the "spacebar", the cursor will move to the next UITextField (i.e. it will prevent you from typing more than one word into the field).

If I was to do this how would I go about it?

I thought I should overwrite the

```
textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)
```

method - is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems reasonable. Why don't you try it? That's how most of us figure this stuff out.

Comment: Also, be sure to think about what you want to do if the range is in the middle of the current string and/or `replacementString` is pasted in and contains a space.

Comment: I think this might be the wrong method however, because I'm not looking to change characters, simply prevent the addition of more when I press the spacebar. @PhillipMills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Get your textFields text
    let str = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    // Check if the last character is a space
    // If true then move to the next textfield
    if str.characters.last! == " "{
        print("SPACE!")
        textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else{
        print(str.characters.last!)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Hi Rashwan, thanks for this answer. I'll look at building on this - it works for the first word, but throws an exception when I go to the next one - (I'm using three UITextFields).

Comment: Are you sure all of the textfields delegates are set?

Comment: @neX, I created a sample project for you that you can work with. You can download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4jiny4ev8kpeki/Test.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
let str = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

if str.characters.last! == " “{
        if textField == textField1{
            textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else  if textField == textField2{
            textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else  if textField == textField3{
                   // do what you want
            }
}
return true
}
```